# Using 3rd party java libraries, like com.jcraft.jsch, with clojure

Tags: java, clojure, libraries, jsch

I'm experimenting with [clojure](http://www.clojure.org) and am trying to get a feel for using 3rd party libraries.  I've been able to download some source, bundle it into a jar file with leiningen, put it in my classpath and (use 'lib.etc) in my script.  I've also played around with the objects in java.lang.*.

I haven't had any success with 3rd party java, though.

```
$ java -cp clojure.jar:clojure-contrib.jar:com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.31.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.1.0
user=> (require 'com.jcraft.jsch)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate com/jcraft/jsch__init.class or com/jcraft/jsch.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

$ jar tf com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.31.jar | egrep "(init|clj)"
$
```

It looks like an __init.class or .clj file must be created.  Is this true, or is there some alternative way that pure java classes are supposed to be loaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For java classes use `import`:

```
(import java.util.ArrayList)

;// or use a prefix for multiple classes:
(import [java.util ArrayList Collection])

;// or preferably in the ns declaration:
(ns my.lib
  [:import [java.util ArrayList Collection]])

user=> (def al (ArrayList.))
#'user/al
user=> (.add al "hi")
true
user=> (.size al)
1
```

Note the package and class names do not need to be quoted since `import` is a macro.

Also there is no equivalent to `import java.util.*;` You need to specify which classes you want to import.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `import` for non-clojure stuff.