# How do I make java libraries visible to clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, jvm

Ultimately, I want the following to work

```
(ns grizzler.core
  (:import (com.sun.grizzly.http.embed GrizzlyWebServer)
           (com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11 GrizzlyAdapter)))
```

However, I have no idea how to go about this. Do I add stuff to my classpath? Where do I modify my classpath, in my .bashrc or within clojure?

I've found the grizzly project at http://grizzly.java.net/. But what do I download? How do I install things? I really just have no idea what to do.

Related: [Using 3rd party java libraries, like com.jcraft.jsch, with clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327176/using-3rd-party-java-libraries-like-com-jcraft-jsch-with-clojure) - except that it's not detailed enough for me :(

**Edit:** I also tried the following in project.clj and it didn't work:

```
(defproject grizzler "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [com.sun.grizzly.http.core "2.1.10"]
                 [com.sun.grizzly.http.embed "2.1.10"]
                 [com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11 "2.1.10"]])
```

In addition, I tried net.java.grizzly.http.core , and that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current consensus on the "right" way to do this is basically "use leiningen". Leiningen is basically a wrapper around maven and uses maven repositories. Most of the time you can find the code you need in a maven repository somewhere, though eventually you will be in this situation where you need to use a jar file. In this case you **install the jar file into your local maven repository** which lives in your home directory and contains copies of all the jars required to build all your projects. In cases where the jars you depend on are available from a central repo this local repo acts as a cache so you don't have to download them every time, though you can manually put jars into your local repo if it can't automatically download them.

I recommend watching this [video](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-use-leiningen-clojure-build-system-380696/) first.

- check carefully to see if the library you need is already available
- download the jar you want
- [download leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen)
- run `lein new nameOfYourProject`
- add it to your leiningen project's `project.clj`
- run `lein deps`

  - this will print the full command for installing the jar file to your local maven repo
  - run this command (as printed by leiningen) and your jar file should be copied to the correct location under ~/.m2/...
  - run `lein deps` again to make sure it finds it
- add an `import` statement in your .clj file (as you have above)
- success!

Debugging this process can be very situation specific, but the denizens of #clojure are usually quite helpful.

Comment: grizzly is available on maven central - http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.2/html/dependencies.html - so you can just specify the dependency in project.clj and Leiningen should be able to find it.

Comment: Thanks Sean - I tried that but I don't think I specified the package correctly. I included details in an edit above.

Comment: Woohoo! Finally got it: [org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-core "2.1.10"] . I had to look at https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-core/maven-metadata.xml to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the package names in your original question and realized they were referring to the Sun versions, not the org.glassfish versions. I tinkered around for 20 minutes but couldn't figure out what the modern equivalents to your packages were.